# Google Maps open infowindow selected geojson data

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I created two different geojson data on the map. I want to click selected geojson data. I used this code its working but I get two geojson id not clicked id. I just want to get clicked geojson id. Here f1 is a defined property.

```
map.data.addListener('click', function(event){
   var id=event.feature.getProperty('f1');
    alert(id);
    infowindow2.setContent(sContent);
    infowindow2.setPosition(event.latLng);
    infowindow2.setOptions({pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0,-34)});
    infowindow2.open(map);
}
```

İt is example of geojson data

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              28.9707230069957,
              41.0143811020089
            ],
            [
              28.9707162564384,
              41.0143424956501
            ],
            [
              28.9707099456323,
              41.0143003832993
            ],
            [
              28.9707027979273,
              41.0142558268809
            ],
            [
              28.970696368278,
              41.0142152406152
            ],
            [
              28.9706905696604,
              41.0141716903304
            ],
            [
              28.9706439363613,
              41.0141812741487
            ],
            [
              28.9706538187623,
              41.0142586346452
            ],
            [
              28.9706604147999,
              41.0143007495466
            ],
            [
              28.9706724204532,
              41.0143865085056
            ],
            [
              28.9707230069957,
              41.0143811020089
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "f1": 110013011,
        "f2": "FATİH",
        "f3": "SURURİ",
        "f4": "F21C25D2C",
        "f5": "P29",
        "f6": "337",
        "f7": "34",
        "f8": "1. Derece Koruma Bolgeleri",
        "f9": null,
        "f10": "Ş",
        "f11": 55,
        "f12": 96,
        "f13": 1121229337,
        "f14": 12,
        "f15": 28.9706822916352,
        "f16": 41.0142812568067,
        "f17": 12,
        "f18": 12,
        "f19": 227,
        "f20": "SURURİ",
        "f21": "e17c8db4-bec3-11e5-b590-00a0d1e9ad00",
        "f22": 10598737,
        "f23": 20598781,
        "f24": "e17c66a4-bec3-11e5-8eec-00a0d1e9ad00"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code/geoJSON: `Uncaught InvalidValueError: in property "features": at index 0: in property "geometry": in property "coordinates": at index 0: first and last positions are not equal` and `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`.  If I fix those: `Uncaught ReferenceError: infowindow2 is not defined`

Comment: I updated full geojson result sorry.

Comment: The main problem seems to be `Uncaught ReferenceError: sContent is not defined`, so I am guessing it is just a typo.

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/so0bb109/)

Comment: Thank you so much your code is working before I used same method but When I click a geometry I get alert count of drawing polygon. What could cause?

Comment: You mean this? `alert(id);`

Comment: yes I mean that